# Dots and empty dots in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I need to draw dots and empty dots in a plot to show the fixed points. They should look like in the figure below: an empty dot (a circle) and a thick dot.

Is there any way to plot something like that?
Thanks

[image: Dots]
<sub>(source: [emathematics.net](http://www.emathematics.net/imagenes/discontinuity2.gif))</sub>

Comment: Yes, you can plot circles, or predefined empty dots etc. What works best depends also on how your data is structured. Can you give an example how your data is structured and how your fixed points are defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to use the built in point types, there are usually (depending on the terminal) a filled circle and an empty circle.  Issuing the `test` command will show you what is available.  For instance, with the wxt terminal, I see

[image]

which shows me that I can get a filled circle with point type 7 and an empty one with point type 6 (we don't worry about the different colors as those are inherited from the line type).

Now, the easy way to get our desired plot is to just issue `plot datafile with points pt 6` or point type 7.  It is trickier if you need it to depend on your data.

Suppose that my data looks like this:

```
1 3 0
5 8 1
2 6 0
3 2 1
```

The first two columns are the x and y coordinates and the third tells me if I should use an empty dot (0) or a filled dot (1).  Unfortunately, gnuplot does not support a variable point type command (something like `plot datafile u 1:2:($3+6) with linespoints pt var`), which is exactly what we need here.

In order to plot our data, we will make two passes.  The first will plot the lines and the empty circles (for all points), and the second will plot the filled circles (for only the points that should be filled - overwriting the empty circles).

```
plot datafile u 1:2 with linespoints pt 6, \
     datafile u 1:($3==1?$2:1/0) with points pt 7 lt 1
```

This command will plot the lines and the empty circles first.  Next it plots the filled circles only when they are needed.  To do this, it computes a conditional y-coordinate.  If the third column is 1, it uses the second column as the y-coordinate.  If not, it uses the invalid value `1/0`, which causes gnuplot to skip the point.  In order to keep the colors and everything else the same, we use lt 1 (which was used by default in the first plot command segment).

[image]

**Note:** I have put in a feature request for a `pointtype variable` option, and it looks like it may work its way into a future version.  A preliminary patch is available implementing this under [feature request 437](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/437/).

**Updated Note:** The `pointtype variable` option is currently availabe in the development version of gnuplot.